# Loading 2 html pages into separate divs at once

Tags: jquery

I have an `index.html` page with a horizontal navigation bar in the centre of the page. There are 6 nav buttons (about_us, faqs, etc etc ....).  Now above the nav bar there is a div called #container_1 and below the nav bar there is a div called #container_2.

I have got the code so far so my nav bar will load the respective html content into the div #container_1 above the nav bar using jQuery.

However, what I need to do is when I click the appropriate navigation button then BOTH divs will simultaneously load their respective html pages.

For example when I click on the about_us button it will load 'about_us.html#content' into div #container_1 as well as 'about_us_2.html#content' into div container_2.

Surely there is something simple I am missing.

I have pasted my code so far.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#navigation a').click(function() {
  $('#slider_1').hide();
  $('#slider_1').load($(this).attr('href')).slideDown(1000);
  return false; 
}).eq(0).click();
});
```

And my HTML code:

```
<div id="container_1">
<div id="slider_1"></div>
```

```
<div id="navigation">
<a href="aboutus.html#content"><img src="images/btn_aboutus.jpg" border="0" /></a> etc etc etc ...
```

```
<div id="container_2">
<div id="slider_2"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code exemple :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdwLC

Comment: hmmm doesn't quite seem to be working, however I will persevere and then post back if I can't get it

Comment: Hi again, good work elasmai, I needed to make a couple of adjustments to your code: I replaced the "this.data('page-one')"  with "this.attr(data-page-one), and it worked!  But you definitely pointed me in the right direction so thanks heaps!!